# Error Icon added to a field label is clickable

Tags: jquery, html, css, validation, label

[image]

Hello,

For field level error validation, we are adding an error icon (X red image) to the field label as a background image. 
Now since its added as a background image to the label, it appears as click-able [but to say only the label is clicked] and when the click is done over the error icon, the focus moves to the field input.
 We can add it as separate img element next to the label, but still

I would like to know is there any way I make that error icon not click-able, still adding it as a background image.  
 Thank you

Comment: show your code and first try yourself help  of google

Comment: Can you post your current html and jQuery to get a better idea of your page structure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cann add css to that element or the parent to avoid it receiving clicks. You didn't post code on your question so here is a general example. I used class `avoid-clicks`, which you should add to the error label or its parent. Just avoid adding on a parent that can be also common for the input field.

```
.avoid-clicks {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Keep in mind also that the user will expect to be able to click on that `X`, and changing expected behaviors is not so appreciated and degrades the user experience on your website.